# JQuery: Build HTML in 'memory' rather than DOM

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to 'pre-build' a snippet of HTML before adding it to the DOM?

For example:

```
$mysnippet.append("<h1>hello</h1>");
$mysnippet.append("<h1>world</h1>");
$("destination").append($mysnippet);
```

where **$mysnippet** doesnt exist in the DOM. I'd like to dynamically build up some lumps of html and then insert them into the page at appropriate points later.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes pretty much exactly how you have done it

Some extension of this...

```
$('<div>').attr('id', 'yourid').addClass('yourclass').append().append()...
```

and then finally

```
.appendTo($("#parentid"));
```

Comment: I'm finding that .wrap() does not work with in-memory/out-of-dom elements.

Answer (score 59):

When dealing with more complex nodes (especially heavily nested ones), it is a better approach to write the node in HTML and set its visibility hidden.

You can then use JQuery's clone() method to make a copy of the node and adapt its contents to your needs.

E.g. with this html:

```
<div class="template-node" style="display:none;">
   <h2>Template Headline</h2>
   <p class="summary">Summary goes here</p>
   <a href="#" class="storylink">View full story</a>
</div>
```

it's much faster and understandable to do:

```
var $clone = $('.template-node').clone();
$clone.find('h2').text('My new headline');
$clone.find('p').text('My article summary');
$clone.find('a').attr('href','article_page.html');
$('#destination').append($clone);
```

than to create the entire node in memory like shown above.

Comment: you forgot that you're appending the clone that's still hidden.. $('#destination').append($clone.show()) will fix that.

Comment: I find it helps to attach the display: none; to the template css class, and then by removing the class from the clone it displays the html when appended.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've started your variable name with a $ sign?

Comment: @Niels it's a (perhaps somewhat exotic) convention that I use myself - variables holding jQuery-selectors are prefixed with `$` to give them some jQuery "flavor" to help distinguish them from other local variables.

Comment: What if I want to make a reusable javascript library? Where do I put the HTML template? You don't want to have to be adding extra html to every page that uses the library. Can't you store the HTML template as a literal in javascript somehow?

Comment: @interstar Once you add html to javascript file you start mixing js with html. IMHO javascript templating is the way to go. Like one developed by [John Resing](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)

Answer (score 9):

Old thread but I bumped into it while searching for the same.

```
var memtag = $('<div />', {
                'class'    : 'yourclass',
                'id'       : 'theId',
                'data-aaa' : 'attributevalue',
                html       : 'text between the div tags'
});
```

`memtag` is now an in memory html tag, and can be inserted into the DOM if you want. If you do such thing with an `img` tag you can 'preload' images into the cache for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just build them as a string:

```
$mysnippet = "<h1>hello</h1>";
$mysnippet = $mysnippet + "<h1>world</h1>";
$("destination").append($mysnippet);
```

Comment: Treating the DOM as text is hacky (the DOM isn't a string, it's just persisted as one), unreliable (it increases the chance of creating something unbalanced) and unnecessary (we have native methods and JQuery to make nodes).

Comment: @mikemaccana Reading DOM creation code is a pain in the ass and DOM creation code is also slower than just giving it a string. Pick your battles.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/appendText

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample =
    $('<div></div>')
        .append(
            $('<div></div>')
                .addClass('testing-attributes')
                .text('testing'))
        .html();
```

Which creates:

```
<div class="testing-attributes">testing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prebuild it and also attach events, as well as data attributes, inner html, etc, etc.

```
var eltProps = {
    css: {
        border: 1,
        "background-color": "red",
        padding: "5px"
    },
    class: "bblock",
    id: "bb_1",
    html: "<span>jQuery</span>",
    data: {
        name: "normal-div",
        role: "building-block"
    },
    click: function() {
         alert("I was clicked. My id is" + $(this).attr("id"));
    }
};

var elt = $("<div/>", eltProps);

$("body").append(elt);
```