# Building HTML (~= DOM) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I may be doing something wrong, but I haven't been able to find a good way to build basic HTML/DOM structures, like lists, dynamically. Simple example would be building a table (table element, row, cells, with properly escaped text content) given input like json (objects).

The problem I have is that most calls (like ".append()", ".html()", ".text()") do not seem to chain in intuitive (to me, anyway) way. For example, you **can't** do something like:

```
$("#divId").append("<table>").append("<tr>").append("<td>").text("some text");
```

text() call seems to wipe out content at main level; and appends likewise add stuff within same scope. I would expect appennd() to return content being added, but it seems to be returning its own context.

I know there is simple "appendText()" extension that helps with last part. But how about others?

For what it's worth, right now I revert back to DOM, by something like

```
$("#divId")[0].appendChild(document.createElement("table"))....
```

but that's pretty verbose.

So I am hoping I am missing something totally obvious... but what? Call other than append()?

I tried browsing jQuery reference docs, googling, but most docs just use "embed all stuff in a string"; which has problems, including that of not quoting textual content properly.

(also: no, this is not a dup of ["JQuery: Build HTML in ‘memory’ rather than DOM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337352/jquery-build-html-in-memory-rather-than-dom)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("#divId").append("<table>").append("<tr>").append("<b>").text("some text");
```

as either:

```
$("#divId").append("<table><tr><td><b>some test</b></td></tr></table>");
```

or

```
$("<b></b>").text("some text").appendTo("<td></td>").appendTo("<tr></tr>").appendTo("<table></table>").appendTo("#divId");
```

Comment: Latter would work -- former has the problem of text potentially having ampersand and less-thans. Second one sounds like it'd do the trick.

I guess I didn't read docs for appendTo() well enough, somehow I thought it wouldn't work this way. Makes total sense if it does, given your sample. :)

Comment: on your third example you can go event shorter and do $('<b />').text('bolded text');

Comment: Hmmh. Actually... because of order reversal (which I missed first) it gets bit tricky, when list entries are added in loop.
But it should be possible still.

Comment: Later versions of jQuery cache the results. This is important in the case of making dynamic lists. `$("<li>"+i+"</li>")` will parse and create a new dom each and every loop (Poor performance) `$("<li/>").test(i)` will cache the li object and change the text every loop. Fast but again not dynamic as it changing the text on the original cached li. if your in a for loop for example you'll need to do a clone(): `$("<li/>").clone().text(i)`

Comment: This last solution doesn't work, the second one is dangerous in case `"some text"` is stored in a variable. This is the first wrong solution I find on SO!

Comment: The first example wipes out whole table with `"some text"`, so it does exactly the same, what author of the question considers as counterintuitive ("_text() call seems to wipe out content at main level; and appends likewise add stuff within same scope._"). And because my edit has been rejected, I'm posting correct (IMHO) version: `$("#divId").append($("<table>").append($("<tr>").text("some text")))` - this version has been posted also in this thread [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8394249/1891695);

Answer (score 7):

You can use `append`:

```
$("#divId").append(
  $("<table/>").append(
    $("<tr/>").append(
      $("<td/>").append(
        $("<b/>").text("some text")
))));
```

If you really insist, you could use `appendTo`, but it's less intuitive, will be slower and takes a few more keystrokes:

```
$("<b/>").text("some text").appendTo(
  $("<td/>").appendTo(
    $("<tr/>").appendTo(
      $("<table/>").appendTo(
        "#divId"
))));
```

In any case, it's important to use `.text("...")` to escape special characters (and avoid XSS attacks).

**Even better**, when you get bored with writing these, you really want to look into [`jsrender`](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender), [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [doT](https://github.com/olado/doT) or any other of the many javascript templating solutions. It allows you to keep your code separate from your HTML (think MVC) and makes it much more clear what you are building. It is much easier to modify too.

Comment: I agree entirely with this answer. Accepted answer has issues - e.g. every example produces different [result](http://jsfiddle.net/fj4wr/1/), which I believe was not intended by the author. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz3xA/1/) are correct results and code from this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quick note: additionally, [AppendDOM](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/appendDom) plugin looks like it can also simplify the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery [createHtml](https://github.com/efunneko/jquery.createHtml) plugin that allows you to do:

```
$("#divId").$table().$tr().$td().$b("some text");
```

It is a bit more convenient that the .append() chain in that you can put html content and attributes in the elements as you string them along:

```
$("#divId").$table({class: "clean"}).$tr().$td({id: "textId"}).$b("some text");
```