# Callback from load with jQuery?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I use PHP and jQuery and here is my code (that works so far).

```
$(".design").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/?addmod_ajax=1",{
    menu: 'layout',
});
```

**This is what I want to do.**

If the PHP-file I'm calling find some values in a PHP array (on the server side), I want the jQuery to append (add) some content to the HTML element. Is it possible to make callbacks like that?

It's important to me that I can still send my POST variables to my PHP file.

Comment: I would use $.ajax() for that matter, wich has callbacks and many other options that might be usefull

Comment: I think so too. A vote up for pointing me the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @yoda said in a comment you can use $.ajax() to acomplish this as shown below:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>",
   data: "addmod_ajax=1",
   success: function(data){
     alert("data is " + data );
   }
 });
```

you can swap type for `POST` if you need to

Comment: "date" should be "data". Could not edit post because stackoverflow only accepts 6 or more character changes.

However it helped me on the way. Green check for that. To help others, correct the error in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate markup and add it to your page with [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function you already have.  I'm going to assume that you are returning JSON from your ajax method:

```
$(".design").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/?addmod_ajax=1",{
    menu: 'layout' }, function(data) { 
 var markup = '<ul>';
 for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++ ) {
markup += '<li><a href="' + data[x].Url + '">'+data[x].Text+'</a></li>';
 }
 markup += '</ul>';
 #('menu').html(markup); });
```

The `load()` function accepts as an optional third argument a function that will work with the response of your ajax call.  In this instance for illustrative purposes I'm assuming you want to build some navigation, so I'm iterating through an array and building an unordered list as I go.

Its possible to have even more control / options with your ajax requests as well.  I recommend you have a look at the the [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for an idea of the things you can do.

It is an older topic, but there is a discussion here on stack overflow that shows various ways you could generate html and insert it into the DOM: [JQuery: Build HTML in 'memory' rather than DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337352/jquery-build-html-in-memory-rather-than-dom).  There is also the `tmpl()` plugin that is very useful for generating markup.  You can learn more about `tmpl()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/).

Comment: It might work. Thanks for your effort. However I solved it with another method.