# cannot pass a string to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to call a function with this line find(\'' + news_text + '\') but it gives me

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

the string might looks like this:"Barnes & Noble to launch video service for Nook\r http://t.co/NTnycGYD"

Here is the code which am tackling with the problem:

```
            function show(news_user, news_date, news_profile_img, news_text, news_url, user_tweets) {
                $('#news-tweets')
                    .css({
                    'overflow-y': 'scroll',
                    'overflow-x': 'hidden'
                });

                $('#news-tweets')
                    .append('<div class="tweets"><div class="user">' + news_user + '</div><div class="date">' + news_date + '</div>\
          <span class="clear">\
          </span><div class="img"><a href="' + news_profile_img + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + news_profile_img + '" width="55" height="50"/>\
          </a></div>\
          <div class="text">' + news_title + '<br /><a onclick="find(\'' + news_text + '\')">Show user tweets..</a></div></div>');
            }

            function find(news_text) {
                $('#user-news-tweets')
                    .html("");
                for (var x = 0; x < user_tweets.length; x++) {
                    var user = user_tweets[x].user;
                    var date = user_tweets[x].date;
                    var profile_img = user_tweets[x].user_profile_img;
                    var url = user_tweets[x].url;
                    var text = user_tweets[x].text;
                    var text3 = text.replace(/\r"\/:\.`'/g, "");
                    if (text3.indexOf(news_text.substr(0, 10)) > -1) {
                        $('#user-news-tweets')
                            .css({
                            'overflow-y': 'scroll',
                            'overflow-x': 'hidden'
                        });
                        $('#user-news-tweets')
                            .append('<div class="tweets"><div class="user">' + user + '</div><div class="date">' + date + '</div>\
                        <span class="clear"></span><div class="img"><a href="' + profile_img + '" target="_blank">\
                        <img src="' + profile_img + '" width="55" height="50"/></a></div>\
                        <div class="text">' + text + '<br /></div>');
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: if you're using jquery already, why would you use string concatenation to build HTML instead of the jquery function?

Comment: @jbabey can you show me what u mean by jquery function?

Comment: for example, `$('<div>').addClass('tweets')` would replace your `'<div class="tweets">'`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337352/jquery-build-html-in-memory-rather-than-dom)

Comment: ok i will try your way..

Comment: u know how to construct it quickly?

Comment: I've produced this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8P4VH/jsfiddle) from your code. Is this what you're trying to achieve?  (PS: This isn't the best way to produce HTML dynamically, but it serves the purpose for testing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try terminating the string, like what the error said.

```
find('\' + news_text + '\')
```

Comment: Thanks @karim79,its working now..i had to escape some characters from the string as well.!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (you were also missing a `div` tag to close your `div.tweets` start). I've always preferred this way of escaping elements over the apostrophe, despite it looking less graceful.  I've included carriage returns for readability to remove them.

```
$("#news-tweets").append("
    <div class=\"tweets\">
        <div class=\"user\">" + news_user + "</div>
        <div class=\"date\">" + news_date + "</div>
        <span class=\"clear\"></span>
        <div class=\"img\">
            <a href=\"" + news_profile_img + "\" target=\"_blank\">
                <img src=\"" + news_profile_img + "\" width=\"55\" height=\"50\" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class=\"text\">" + news_text + "<br />
            <a onclick=\"find(\"" + news_text + "\");\">Show user tweets..</a>
        </div>
    </div>
");​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: it gives me SyntaxError: illegal character
[Break On This Error]  

</div>");​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @ak_47 don't keep the formatting I have, I used that for readability - make sure you remove all spaces so you collapse the entire string.