# Can't insert html using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to create HTML like this

```
<div id="positional">
   <div>
    <div>
       <label for='azimuth'>Azimuth</label>
    </div>
    <div>
       <input id='azimuth'>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to use this, but I can't get it to work, can you help?

```
$("<div><input id='azimuth'></div>")
.insertAfter("<div><label for='azimuth'>Azimuth</label></div>")
.wrap("<div></div>")
.appendTo("#positional");
```

Assume `<div id="Positional">` has already been created. Thanks, I'm pulling my hair out.

EDIT: I know I could just hand insert the HTML in one unreadable blob, but I'm trying to do it step by step and understand the problem. In this the div containing the label doesn't appear.

EDIT2: Seriously, if anyone could explain why this doesn't work, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Why are you breaking it up into several methods?

Comment: what content are already there?\

Comment: What's wrong with `html()`? `$('#positional').html("<div><div><label for='azimuth'>Azimuth</label></div><div><input id='azimuth'></div></div>')`

Comment: `$("#positional").append("<div><div><label for='azimuth'>Azimuth</label></div><div><input id='azimuth'></div></div>");` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/0pudh3o5/)

Comment: My blob is certainly not unreadable, sir. Thou has deeply offended. Pistols at dawn!

Comment: Is there a requirement missing?  Where is the html to place in the #positional element coming from?  Is there a button that adds the input.  Is it an AJAX request putting some html in the placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.wrap`, `$.after`, `$.appendTo` don't work with in memory nodes. See [JQuery: Build HTML in 'memory' rather than DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337352/jquery-build-html-in-memory-rather-than-dom)

Put your starting node into the DOM before calling those methods http://jsfiddle.net/j824yyng/2/

```
$("<div><label for='azimuth'>Azimuth</label></div>")
.appendTo("#positional")
.wrap("<div></div>")
.after("<div><input id='azimuth'></div>");
```

As others have pointed out, this is not very readable. It may be a good lesson in `jQuery` but I would hate you if I had to modify the code above instead of the straight forward version.

Answer (score 5):

Unless there's more to the story than what you've mentioned, this should do fine.

```
var myHtml = '<div>'
    + '<div>'
    + '   <label for="azimuth">Azimuth</label>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div>'
    + '   <input id="azimuth">'
    + '</div>'
    + '</div>';

$('#positional').html(myHtml);
```

Comment: I'll stay in the comments this time.

Comment: No I just wanted to do it using JQuery operators and understand why it wasn't working.

Comment: Fair enough, but then your question is too broad. You'll want to break it up into individual methods and study each step. That said, I'd consider this solution much more readable than what's in your OP, unless a person is very well versed in jQuery-ese.

Comment: One thing that some love about jQuery is this ability to chain commands. I absolutely abhor it, it does not make it easier to read in but a few cases and it always makes it harder to debug besides ruining meaningful code coverage. However, this does not explain what the problem with the code is. [My answer does explain what the problem is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25315363/227299), points out a solution like what the OP wants and does point out that your suggestion is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#positional').html('<div><div><label for="azimuth">Azimuth</label></div><div><input id="azimuth"></div></div>');
```

Comment: This seems to be what you would do if an AJAX request returned an html blob to put in a container.  Short of more requirements in the question, this is a good answer.